# Create grouped barplot

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe, which looks like:

I want to compare the control group, with the combined group lkC & lC and the combined group tkC & tC. Therefore, I want to create a grouped barplot, which shows the 3 different groups (control, l, t) and their weight means (weight_M). Furthermore, the standard error (weight_SE) should be shown in the graphic.
Any ideas?

Dataframe:

[image]

Barplot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I would suggest you use a boxplot, possibly with jittered dots over it instead of dynamite plots like the ones you are showing. If you start with the raw data, the ggplot2 package can do what you want with something like: `ggplot(Data,aes(x=ltControl,y=weight_M,fill=kcC)) + geom_boxplot()`